# How do we access Vert, Norm and UV data then print to a text file using Blender/Python?

Tags: python

Basically, I've been trying to implement the code from the following page but I'm having difficulty tying the subtleties together.

[Get indices of vertices of triangulated faces in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3637/get-indices-of-vertices-of-triangulated-faces-in-python/3657#3657)

The block that is over a light gray rectangle is the array that will be passed to a VBO.  That is what I'd like that output from Blender to look like.

For the example code I am using, I would like to change every instance of the following:

`print(indices)`
or
`print(plain_verts)`

into something that will print to a text file in a specified folder on my hardrive.

***To address a comment that was made:***My question has nothing really to do with C/C++, what I am looking for is the Blender Python equivalent so that I can end up with the same file which is the Vertex, normals and uvCoords. In a 1 dimensional floating point array.  Basically I need a Python script that can emulate the following code.  I want to replace all the fluff below with a script that is run from within Blender.

[image]
So basically, how do I end up with text with a file that has something like the following in it?  By using Python in Blender.

For example it would be called  ***modelName.txt*** and would contain the following.

```
GLfloat modelName[] = 
{
    vertex, normal, uv,      #Vertex 1 
    vertex, normal, uv,      #Vertex 2
    vertex, normal, uv,      #Vertex 3 
};
```

Comment: Basically this is can be viewed as a tutorial or a script request however it is pretty fundamental for game devs and import/export writers so a working script would be very beneficial for the overall Blender knowledge base.

Comment: It could easily be a plugin which people can alter so they can always output their choice of VBO format for specific models. 

This offers great optimization opportunities for a game engine to take advantage of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to export the triangles of the default scene's cube the process would be as follows.

- Select the Cube, switch to *Edit Mode*
- Select all faces
- Load the Texture in UV-Image Editor
- UV-Unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> Smart UV-Project
- Create a Material and Texture , assign the texture and UV-Map
- Convert the quads to tris <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>
- Switch to *Object Mode* (Important)

Run the script:

```
import bpy

#bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris()

ob = bpy.context.object

with open("c:\\tmp\\{ob.name}.txt".format(ob=ob), "w") as file:
    file.write("GLfloat {ob.name}[] =\n{\n".format(ob=ob))

    for face in ob.data.polygons:
        for vert, loop in zip(face.vertices, face.loop_indices):
            coord = ob.data.vertices[vert].normal
            normal = ob.data.vertices[vert].co
            uv = ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop].uv
            file.write("\t{co.x}, {co.y}, {co.z}, {n.x}, {n.y}, {n.z}, {uv.x}, {uv.y},\n".format(co=coord, n=normal, uv=uv))

    file.write( "};\n")
```

Find the output file in the temp directory:

```
GLfloat Cube[] =  
{
    0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.333333,
    0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.666667,
    0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, 1.000000 0.999999 1.000000, 0.333333, 0.666667,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000, 0.333333, 0.333333,
    0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000, 0.666667, 0.666667,
    0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.333333,
    0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, 1.000000 0.999999 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.333333,
    0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.000000,
    0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.333333,
    0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000, 0.333333, 0.000000,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.000000,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.333333,
    0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, 1.000000 0.999999 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.333333,
    0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.666667,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.666667,
    0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.666667,
    0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, 1.000000 0.999999 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.333333,
    0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
    0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.000000,
    0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.333333, 0.666667,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.666667,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000, 0.333333, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000, 0.666667, 0.333334,
    0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000, 0.666667, 0.666667,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.333333,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.000000,
    -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.333333,
    0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000, 0.333333, 0.000000,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000, 0.666667, 0.000000,
    -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000, 0.666667, 0.333333,
};
```

The code is based on ideasman42 answer here: [Exporting UV coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4820/exporting-uv-coordinates)

[.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26401) as demo.

Comment: @ CoDEmanX I removed the previous answer it was too messy since the topic changed. Thanks for your input and edits there.

Comment: @jasperge Thanks for cleaning up, but I get now: ValueError: unmatched '{' in format
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

Comment: My bad, the line `file.write("GLfloat {ob.name}[] =\n{\n".format(ob=ob))` should read: `file.write("GLfloat {ob.name}[] =\n{{\n".format(ob=ob))` (notice the double '{'). I can't make the edit, because an edit needs to be at least 6 characters :(