# Export simple model with texture to three.js

Tags: texturing, uv, export, collada, three.js

I am trying export Blender models to [threejs.org](http://threejs.org) as DAE model but have problem with models with texture.

To make things simpler, here are the steps I perform (and fail) to add texture to simple "Startup file" which contains a cube, camera, and light:

1. Select the cube
2. In the **Materials** panel, make sure the default Material for the cube is selected.
3. In the **Texture** panel, make sure "Tex" (the default texture for the material) is selected.
4. For this texture, set **Type** to "Image or Movie"
5. In the **Image** section of panel, open a grass1.jpg (a 512x512 image) as the texture.
6. In the **Mapping** section, change the **Coordinates** to UV.
7. Export the model as **Collada** model, checking "Include UV Textures", "Include Material Textures", and "Copy" checkboxes.

You can [download blend, dae, and texture file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xoao6g6xzoSlE2TnFxMV9EdlE/edit?usp=sharing) mentioned in these steps.

Then I use the following code to load the DAE model, but I get this error and the cube is not shown:

> 256 [.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION :
>   glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2
>   WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.

[image]

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script>
    var scene, camera, renderer;
    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 10000);
        camera.position.set(10,10,10);
        scene.add(camera);

        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
            HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        });  

        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

        loader.load( 'models/untitled.dae', function(geometry) {
            dae = geometry.scene;
            scene.add(dae);
            var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
            gridXZ.setColors( new THREE.Color(0x8f8f8f), new THREE.Color(0x8f8f8f) );
            gridXZ.position.set(0,0,0);
            scene.add(gridXZ);
        });

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    }

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      controls.update();
    }
</script>
```

And here is the screenshot of Blender after mentioned 7 steps:

[image]

**Update:** Exporting as js file using [JSON exporter for Blender](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) doesn't work either.

Comment: What formats does three.js accept? Have you tried exporting to a different format?

Comment: Also, you might try asking this question on either gamedev.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com. This isn't really a Blender question, but a three.js question.

Comment: http://solutiondesign.com/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mapping/ describes how to setup the uv map programmatically you could use this with http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6403/how-do-we-access-vert-norm-and-uv-data-then-print-to-a-text-file-using-blender

Comment: @Justin: I exported the model as a JSON file, got the exactly same error. And while I agree that this question is not directly about Blender, I thought people over here have more knowledge about the textures and decided to give it a try.

Comment: @stacker: Thanks but I am trying to avoid modifying the model in the code and do all the model design inside Blender.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error with a three.js script.

Comment: @David: I thought this issue is caused by Blender during exporting the model. I've asked the question on gamedev too and remove this one if didn't get anywhere.

Comment: It does not sound like a DAE export issue, but to check import the exported dae back in to blender. If it looks ok, then it probably is a problem with the three.js script.

Comment: I asked this question on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866748) and the guys there suggested to "unwrap" my model to generate its UV coordinates. I guess this question can be closed here.