# Export OBJ without texture data on faces (but with UV coordinates)

Tags: uv, objects, export, faces

What I want to do is export my mesh (OBJ) without the texture information written to the faces, for example:

```
v 162.319473 -0.732841 161.752060
v ...
vt 10.000000 -20.975000
vt ...
f 1/1 2/2 3/3
f 4/4 1/1 3/3
```

Should be:

```
v 162.319473 -0.732841 161.752060
v ...
vt 10.000000 -20.975000
vt ...
f 1 2 3
f 4 1 3
```

I still want the texture coordinates on my .obj file, I just don't need them written to faces. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple change to the export script. Did you take a look?

Comment: Not really, I didn't evek know you could script export settings (thought that a gui option for this could exist). I will take a look at it, thank you.

Comment: You could also extend this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6403/how-do-we-access-vert-norm-and-uv-data-then-print-to-a-text-file-using-blender/6431#6431

Comment: I ended up just updating my OBJ Loader, but thank you anyway, it will help me learn Blender scripting!